# Color select in asp.net web forms

Tags: asp.net, html, webforms, color-picker

I am new to web and asp.net and want to implement color select in text box, I searched online but all are done using javascript,jquery etc. I tried it using dropdown but the dropdown list gets big and doesn't look good. Is there a way to implement it in asp.net only(using some library).
any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You can go HTML native:

http://www.w3schools.com/colors/colors_picker.asp

If you need to support older browsers and don't want to think about JavaScript:

- AjaxToolkit: https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/ajax-control-toolkit/colorpicker/using-the-colorpicker-control-extender-cs
- Telerik: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/colorpicker/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx
- You can find more solutions on the web if you search for "asp.net colorpicker control"

Hope that helps :)